# Custom sharepoint development with html and javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I am developing sharepoint applications. I want to use html, javascript etc. for user interface. To do that i created script and style files under Masterpage gallery, aspx pages under layouts folder and give reference from aspx to these scripts. But it is hard to maintain development like this because I am using Sharepoint Designer to code javascript. Also I am using ajax requests for data transfer. 
How should I build architecture to achieve this?

Comment: Aren't you using Visual Studio? You can code UserControls and then add them to your sharepoint site with the SmartParts.

Comment: Are you building full custom solutions or just modifying the OOTB forms within SharePoint?

Comment: Yes I am using visual studio but I don t want to code webforms, I want to build full custom solution because my intention is to display list items more user friendly

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this using a combination of JS files, CS files along with SharePoint Designer and Visual Code.

Using Code create and modify your CSS and JS files to make the changes you want to the form.  Doing it this way you aren't creating from scratch but instead are modifying and improving what SharePoint is already providing.  You can also enhance the form even more using JSOM.  Once you have the CSS and JS files created, save them to a location within your Site Collection (maybe the Assets library).

From there, go to SharePoint Designer and access the list you wish to modify.  Select the form you want to update and select View in Browser.  Designer will open a blank form for you.  You can now edit the page and perform the following:

- Click on Add a Web Part
- Add a Content Editor Web Part
- Set Chrome type = None
- Place cursor within the Content editor.  Click on Edit Source within the Ribbon
- Add: `<link href="/<sitename>/SiteAssets/<folder with files>/<cssFilecreated>.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`  (this adds your custom CSS to the form.
- Next edit the list item web form web part
- Set Chrome type = None
- Under Miscellaneous add the following to the JS Link: `~site/SiteAssets/<folder with files>/jquery-1.11.1.min.js|~site/SiteAssets/<folder with files>/JSFileYouCreated.js`

Test out your code to see if it looks the way you want.  If not, re-open the code directly from the Site Assets library.

Quick Note:  I only included the jquery libary to show you how to include multiple files in a JSLink field.  You don't have to use JQuery and can instead use Client-Side Rendering.  It's entirely up to you.  You can separate your AJAX calls into a separate js file if you want too.

Hope this helps some.

Dave

Answer (score 0):

When I do this kind of *development* (I prefer to call it: creating power-solutions) I create some css and JS files and put them in a document library. Typically you use the Assets library but I can be any document library.

When the files are uploaded you can edit them by opening the document library in Explorer view (then you get a *folder* with the files).

To do some fancy stuff at the UI I add an HTML form webpart to a page an put the HTML code in there.